# How to solve: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.40 and higher

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated the Kotlin version but still have this error:

```
* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.40 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':geoflutterfire' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31
```

So I guess it's the geoflutterfire version, but have no idea which version is compatible with  the required version of Kotlin.

If there's any additional information required, I'll be happy to post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not the ***Kotlin*** version, but instead the ***Kotlin Gradle plugin*** version.

With that said, you're getting this error because the dependency `geoflutterfire` doesn't meet the minimal required version of *Kotlin Gradle plugin* for *Android Gradle plugin* to work properly.

You should verify if you have the latest version of `geoflutterfire`, in order to check whether they have updated their *Kotlin Gradle plugin* version or not. If you get the same error with the latest version of `geoflutterfire`, unfortunately, you won't be able to use it for now.

Comment: Additional help, the latest version of the `getflutterfire` dependency is  `3.0.3`.

https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire/changelog

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is nothing you can do as the latest version of the [geoflutterfire](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire) is 3.0.3 (1.3.31) which is lower than your kotlin gradle supported version (1.3.40)

The solution is to downgrade your kotlin version. Here is the step (AS Chipmunk):

1. Open your settings
2. Choose plugins
3. Click on the gear icon
4. And select install plugin from disk

[image]

You can choose and download the kotlin gradle version you want [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/versions)